# Make calculation with variables of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I have an array of 222 rows and 3 columns. 222 should represent the amount of produced spheres I have and the 3 columns x,y and z position.

Now I would like to move the last sphere (sphere 222) in a sine wave manner and I like that the other spheres take this position over. In other words

y(221)=y(222)

t= t-1

It means that I need access to 222 for x, for y and for z whereas

x should be:

```
//
    float functionXvalue = 221 * scaleInputRange / 222; 
    if (animate) {
        functionXvalue += Time.time * animSpeed;
```

y should be:

```
//
float ComputeFunction(float x)
{
    return Mathf.Sin(x);  
}
```

and z: 
zero

How can I access the values in my array and make these calculations?

Edit: 
So far I have this:

```
// Update is called once per frame (ORIGINAL) 
void Update()
{

    //int initialpos = 10; 
    //create an array with 3 columns (x,y,z) and numberOfPoints rows 
    //Vector3[] arrayPosSpheres=new Vector3[(int)(20/(sizeSphere*overlay))]; 

    for (int j = 0; j < 221; j++) {


        for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {



            arrayPosSpheres [j] [p] = arrayPosSpheres [j + 1] [p + 1]; 
        }

    }

    //
    float functionXvalue = 221 * scaleInputRange / 222; 
    if (animate) {
        functionXvalue += Time.time * animSpeed; 

    }


    arrayPosSpheres [221] [0] = functionXvalue;
    arrayPosSpheres [221] [1] = ComputeFunction (functionXvalue) * scaleResult;
    arrayPosSpheres [221] [2] = 0; 





    for (int m = 221; m = 0; m--) {


        for (int q = 0; q < 3; q++) { 

            // access of x,y and z values of sphere 221 
            plotPoints [m].transform.position = arrayPosSpheres [m] [q]; 


        }


    }





float ComputeFunction (float x)
{
    return Mathf.Sin(x);  
}




}
```

But I got many erros...

Assets/Scripts/SineWaveSpheres.cs(135,33): error CS0022: Wrong number of indexes `1' inside [], expected`2'

Assets/Scripts/SineWaveSpheres.cs(156,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to`bool'

Comment: Have a look at this MSDN articles: [Arrays - C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) and [Arrays Tutorial C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Its 2016!  They cheated us out of flying cars and robot dogs, but we do  have classes and generic collections.  You could have a class that defines `{X, Y, Z}` (and optionally name or index them) and a `List<PointX>` so your data storage is easier to use, read, maintain, store and manage

Comment: I do not know List<PointX>. I tried something with array. However I got an error concerning the function I use... see edit. Please some help. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of a `List<PointX>` you might want to work with a `Queue<PointX>`, then when you add a new item just add a item to the end of a list and remove one from the beginning.